# Android Custom List Row

Tags: android, xml, listview, row

i have a trouble my creating my own ListRow. If i only use 1 LinearLayout it works fine, but when i tried this:

**ListRow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:text="@string/unknown"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
         />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

when i trie this, it´s shown only the first Textview and ignore everything which is in the secons LinearLayout. What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation of your `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`, but your first `TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Change it to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` or set your `LinearLayout orientation` to `vertical`.

Comment: I would add an extra alternative: if you want to have all TextViews in a horizontal layout, why not put all of them in a single LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes didn't even noticed that. Agreed :)

Comment: Thanks, i changed the orientation of the first LinearLayout to vertical. I wanted 2 Lines, in the first line i just wanted the first textview. So now it´s perfekt. Thanks anyway gunar

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you need an horizontal linear layout inside another horizontal layout, because you don't have any special attributes on it.

Just switch from "match_parent" to "wrap_content" on your first text view's width, get rid of the extra linear layout and put all your text views in the top level linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:text="@string/unknown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown" />

</LinearLayout>
```